# Converse to a proposition on homogeneous polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I know that for a homogeneous polynomial $P$, if $P(x_1, ... , x_n) = 0$, then $P(ax_1, ..., ax_n) = 0$ for every $a$ in the field of $P$. Is the converse of this proposition true? That is, if $P(x_1, ... , x_n) =0$ implies $P(ax_1, ..., ax_n) = 0$ for every $a$ in the field of $P$, is $P$ homogeneous?

Comment: I'd say this is essentially correct but you have to make some amends to deal with pathological cases like $x^2 + 1$ over $\mathbb{R}$. It is clearly not homogeneous, but since it has no zeroes every zero vacuously satisfies the condition that all its scalar multiples are also zeroes.

Comment: What about $P(x,y) = x^2 + y^4$ over $\mathbb R$? $x^2 + y^4 = 0$ implies that $x = y = 0$ and then clearly $P(ax,ay) = 0$ aswell but $P$ is not homogeneous. Maybe require that your field is algebraically closed or something? Just guessing. You would also need nonzero characteristic I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are assuming that we are working on field of characteristic $0$.

Let $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ be a root of $P$. Then consider the one variable polynomial $Q(t)=P(tx_1,tx_2,\ldots,tx_n)$. Hence $Q(a)=0$ for any $a$ in the field implies all the coefficients of $Q$ are $0$. What are the coefficients of $Q$ ? Write $P(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ as sum of monomials and proceed. I think it will work.

The coefficient of $X^d$ in $Q(X)$ is infact a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ in the variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$.

$P(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ can be represented as follows,

$$\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_jR_j(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$$

Where $m$ is the degree of $P$ and each $R_j$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $j$ with $R_j(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=0$ for all $1\leq j\leq m$. Moreover $a_m\neq0$.

Comment: $Q(a) = 0$ for all $a$ implying that the coefficients of $Q$ are zero is not true over a field with nonzero characteristic. Take $x - x^2$ over $\mathbb F_2$ for example.

Comment: Yeah. I actually meant here for field of characteristic $0$. Sorry I have missed it. Thanks

Comment: I don't see how this proves the statement, $P(x,y) = x^2 + y^4$ over $\mathbb R$ is a counterexample, it is only zero when $x = y = 0$ and then obviously $P(ax,ay) = 0$ aswell for all $a \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @NoelLundstrom your polynomial is not a counter example. Because, we can write it as follows. $$P(x,y)=a_1R_1(x,y)+a_2R_2(x,y)+a_3R_3(x,y)+a_4R_4(x,y)$$ where $a_1=a_3=0$. $a_2=a_4=1$ and $R_2(x,y)=x^2$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree 2; $R_4(x,y)=y^4$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree 4.

Comment: A sum of homogeneous polynomials is not necessarily a homogeneous polynomial. All summands have to be of the same degree for that to happen. Look up the definition of a homogeneous polynomial. $x^2 + y^4$ is not homogeneous.

Comment: @NoelLundström I didn't prove that $P$ will be homogeneous. You please look at my solution. I found the general form of the polynomial $P$ satisfying the hypothesis. My proof indeed shows that $P$ must not necessarily be homogeneous.

Comment: In that case your answer is very misleading, you don't say what you actually prove in your statement and what youre conclusion is.